# Unexpected $end on php page

Tags: php

Hey im new enough to programming was wondering if anyone could help me with this error

( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\game\units.php on line 153

I still dont understand how i put code on this without an error so here it is on pastebin

[units.php](http://pastebin.com/BKUHsgby)

Thanks in advance

Comment: No need to repeat what is already said in an answer when you've marked it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search learns me you opened 30 curly brackets, but only closed 27.

Make sure you close every bracket that you opened.

Answer (score 0):

On line `152` add a `}`

You're missing one. The `$end` error is saying "why is the script already ending, there should be more code here" - That missing code is the curly bracket you forgot to close

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing brace for the `else` statement after `if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {`
.  This is fixed simply by adding another closing brace after the very last one, but you may want to double-check that everything is nested properly as well as fix the indentation of the closing brace for `elseif(isset($_POST['untrain'])) {`

Answer (score 0):

this error means your {brackets} are not matched properly

looking at your code, you never close yoru first if statement

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
...
}else{
```